# Can I convert in C ++ like this: int ('a')?

Tags: c++, variables, data-conversion

I can see everywhere that the standard for converting, for example, from char to int in C++ is

```
(int) 'a'
```

But could I also do this conversion like in python i.e.

```
int ('a')
```

?
To be clear, it works. I'm just asking if you can do that.

Comment: Yes, you can. It's called a "function-style cast" and there are other questions/answers on Stack Overflow that discuss it's merits (or otherwise) in some detail.

Comment: Related, that's a C-style cast.  As in, what the C language uses.  Not recommended in C++.